# How to enable/allow "Insecure content" in chrome site settings using selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver, ui-automation, browser-automation

Images are NOT loading because "Insecure content" in chrome is "Blocked". How to overcome this during automation testing using selenium ? PFA image.
NOTE: This not "Not secure" which displays in address bar.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete script with the options you want:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
options.add_argument("--allow-insecure-localhost")
options.add_argument("--allow-running-insecure-content")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
# ...
driver.quit()
```

You might not need all those options, but definitely the first.